# Why does objdump not show .symtab section while readelf does?

Tags: c, linker, elf

I compile a simple program with gcc and if I see the section header using objdump, it does not show the section `.symtab`. for the same `a.out` file, readelf shows the section:

```
[25] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 000ca4 000480 10     26  2c  4
[26] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 001124 00025c 00      0   0  1
```

Why?

In the default linker script I don't find a definition for `.symtab` section.
If I add a definition by myself like in the linker script :

```
....
PROVIDE(__start_sym)
.symtab : { *(.symtab)}
PROVIDE(__end_sym)
....
```

the difference b/w the addresses of `__start_sym` and `__end_sym` is zero, which means no such section is added in the output file.

But the readelf is able to read the section and dump the contents of this section .. How ? why ?

Comment: `objdump -t file` and `readelf -s file` should give same info in a different way

Answer (score 2):

Of course the `symtab` section is present; the tools just provide information in a different way. The symtab is listed as a dynamic section in objdump (try `-x`) in this form (or alike)

```
...
  STRTAB               0x08048408
  SYMTAB               0x08048178
  STRSZ                0x0000016d
...
```

Objdump seems more focusing on the file as "object" (allowing e.g. to disassemble too), while readelf more on the information ELF format can provide, i.e. on the file "structure" itself.